# Email Notifications of new posts to users - suggestions

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, email, subscription

I currently am using the Subscriber2 plugin to send email notifications to subscribers of new blog posts, but that plugin has not been working properly for a while on my site.

Can someone suggest some alternative plugins.

I only need the following...
- sends emails with part of the post to subscribers on a mailing list
- sidebar widget so new subscribers can enter their email address to sign up
- import feature so I can take emails and import them into this new system

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using feedburner? I'm using feedburner to handle subscribers. And it emails subscribers once a new post is made.

You should be able to import your subscribers by emailing the csv file to feedback@feedburner.com and informing support that you are moving to use Feedburner.

Comment: **Important:** The [Google Feedburner APIs](https://developers.google.com/feedburner/) have been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011 will be shut down on October 20, 2012.

Comment: Although feedburner still works, i will advice you use the RSS to email feature of your email service provider such as MailChimp or use any of the [new post notification plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailoptin/) to send email to your users when you publish a new post.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend MailChimp.  There's an RSS to Email Campaign that is nice and customizable.  Free up to 2000 subscribers.  The RSS URL is `example.com/feed/`

And MailChimp has subscription plugins, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I want to 2nd using Feedburner. I use it for our email subscriptions and it's been great.  You get stats of how many people are clicking through, the daily interaction numbers, etc. Have you tried Feedburner?